# com.android.volley.NoConnectionError after pausing app

Tags: android, android-volley, okhttp

I'm writing my app with Google Volley and Gson to talk to a REST service with OkHttp as HTTP-Stack. That works good most of the time but when I pause my app and return to it the HTTP requests don't work with this Exception:

```
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827): com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.EOFException
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:125)
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827):     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:105)
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827): Caused by: java.io.EOFException
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827):     at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readFully(GZIPInputStream.java:206)
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827):     at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:98)
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827):     at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:81)
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.initContentStream(HttpEngine.java:461)
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:659)
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:346)
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:295)
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:489)
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827):     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
     09-08 19:29:19.611: E/ASDF(21827):     ... 1 more
```

That happens randomly. Not everytime I pause my application. I really have no idea where to start.

Comment: Does this still ocur turning off wifi optimization (Setttings > Wifi > Menu (three dots button) > Advanced > Wifi optimization  OR modify the sleep policy)?  If so,  chances are the device is trying to re-init the wifi connection while you are making an http request and it is not ready. HTHs!

Comment: Let's give it a try. So to put your suggestion in other words: If this EOFException occurs, I should just retry adding the request?

Comment: Did try it out. Same result. The error is pretty easy to reproduce: Just pause the application and restart it. Even reinstalling it in eclipse does produce the error. But deinstall it before manually and reinstall it and everything's fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that this issue is caused by an bug in Android itself which should be fixed!? The issue and its fix is descriped here: [Android issue 24672](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24672)

So adding this piece of code to my OkHttp URLConnection factory fixed the issue right away:

```
  @Override protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = client.open(url);
    // Fix for bug in Android runtime(!!!):
    // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24672
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "");

    return connection;
  }
```

Comment: I'm using volley library. How to override createConnection? There is no such a function!

Comment: As I state above the piece of code: That's a piece of code in the OkHttp HttpStack class not volley itself! You have to write a HttpStack, there you can set the header accordingly.

Comment: The easisest way arround would be to use OkHttp as stack. Or you modify the OkHttp example: https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/5616899

Comment: See this to learn how to override Volley connection properties: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25887160/369317

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for about an hour. If you are trying to connect to a virtual machine rest service you need to change the hosts file on the android emulator.

I was puzzled for so long because I had already done this. I don't think it keeps the hosts file between reboots of the emulator. Which is annoying but now I (and maybe you) know...