# NoConnectionError in android volley

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking

The following is my code. I get  **com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.InterruptedIOException** for the first time and for the second time it works fine. There server response is also fine, No error in server side.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, null,
            new Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject responseJsonObject) {
                    try {
                        if (responseJsonObject.has("user")
                                && !responseJsonObject
                                        .isNull("user")) {
                                user.jsonParser(responseJsonObject
                                    .getJSONObject("user"));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error Occured",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d("Volley Error", volleyError.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Connectivity Error",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    queue.add(request);
    progressDialog.show();
    queue.start();
```

Comment: Can you post the exact log, that might be helpful. For example: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found

Comment: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.InterruptedIOException

Comment: Sorry buddy, no idea.. Just check if this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686671/com-android-volley-noconnectionerror-after-pausing-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910575/how-to-get-access-token-paypal-in-android need help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158858/random-com-android-volley-noconnection-error-java-io-interruptedioexception-st/31181611#31181611

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by removing the following line

```
queue.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. The question [Vamsi referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686671/com-android-volley-noconnectionerror-after-pausing-app) has a workaround using OkHttp that you works if you use OkHttp as the stack in volley (see also the comments in that question [on how to use OkHttp in volley](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/5616899)).

However, here is another hacky workaround that doesn't involve using another library:

```
final RequestQueue requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

final class ErrorFirstTimeHack {
    boolean first_time = true;
    MyVolleyJsonObjectRequest request = null;
}
final ErrorFirstTimeHack errorFirstTimeHack = new ErrorFirstTimeHack();
final MyVolleyJsonObjectRequest request = buildRequestObject(
    Request.Method.GET,
    url,
    new Response.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Object response) {
            // normal success processing
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (error instanceof com.android.volley.NoConnectionError) {
                if (errorFirstTimeHack.first_time) {
                    errorFirstTimeHack.first_time = false;
                    requestQueue.add(errorFirstTimeHack.request);
                    return;
                }
            }
            // normal error processing
        }
    }
);
errorFirstTimeHack.request = request;
requestQueue.add(request);
```